# Debugging simple VBA program

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn VBA. I set myself an exercise to create an array and put numbers consecutively row by row into the array and then into a spreadsheet.

```
Sub ArrayPractice()

Dim NRows As Integer
Dim NCols As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim Alpha As String


Alpha = Split("A @ B @ C @ D @ E @ F @ G @ H @ I @ J @ K @ L @ M @ N @ O @ P @ Q @ R @ S @ T @ U @ V @ W @ X @ Y @ Z", " @ ")

NRows = CInt(InputBox("How Many Rows"))
NCols = CInt(InputBox("How Many Columns (Max is 26)"))

Dim MyArray(1 To NRows, 1 To NCols)

m = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 1)
        MyArray(i, j) = m
        m = m + 1
    Next
Next

For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 1)
        Range(Alpha(j) & i).Value = MyArray(i, j)
    Next
Next
    

End Sub
```

When I try to run it, it hangs up on NCols in

```
Dim MyArray(1 To NRows, 1 To NCols)
```

The error message is "Constant expression required"

Any help?

Comment: Dim happens at compile time, so the values of any arguments used to size your array need to be known at that time.  If you want to size an array using a variable, you need ReDim

Comment: In other words, you should use `Dim MyArray` followed by `ReDim MyArray(1 To NRows, 1 To NCols)`, of course, after having the two used variables filled with appropriate numbers. I mean `NRows` and `NCols`...

Comment: Side note: since you are learning,  creating an `A1` style range address is not necessary and undesirable.   Use `Cells( yourRowNumber, yourColumnNumber)`

Comment: ... best not to rely on implicit ActiveSheet.  Specify the worksheetyou want.  Eg `WorkSheets("yourSheetName").Cells( ... )`

Comment: ... no need to loop to place an array on a sheet.  Use `Cells( yourTopLeftCell ).Resize( NRows, NCols).Value2 = MyArray`

Comment: Thanks all. I did see about the Cells command but haven't had time to read up/try it out.

ReDim solved the first problem.